# Adding html tags to php echo

Tags: php, html

Just wondering, what is the correct way to add HTML `<strong>` tags or anything else for that matter to this?

`echo $row->title`

I did this

`echo '<strong>'.$row->title.'</strong>';`

Comment: What you've done is fine. Sure there are different ways to achieve the same output but if your above code is easy to read for you, then no need to change it.

Comment: `<strong><?=$row->title?></strong>`

Comment: @Andrew: And watch your code fall to pieces if it's ever used on a server with `shorttags=FALSE`

Comment: Oh, don't be dramatic. He could test that one line, if it doesn't work, no big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing it is perfectly fine. However, don't forget that you might need to escape html characters unless HTML should be allowed (which is unlikely in a "title").

```
echo '<strong>'.htmlspecialchars($row->title).'</strong>';
```

This would escape <> and some other special characters.

Answer (score 1):

There is no wrong or correct way to do it. Do it like it is best readable for you (and this is a subjective question). But try to develop a standard and don't do it in a different way everytime.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this

```
echo "<strong>{$row->title}</strong>";
```